# Typeorm - mysql strict mode - incorrect date value

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I am using typeorm and mysql strict mode is enabled on my hosting server. when I try to save a Date object, I get an error:

```
Incorrect date value: '2022-08-22T00:00:00.000Z' for column `table`.`from`
```

This is my entity:

```
    @Entity('table')
    export class Table {
    
        @Column({type: 'date'})
        @Index()
        from: Date;
    }
```

I tried to use @BeforeInsert, but I can't assign a string to the Date type:

```
   @BeforeInsert()
    updateDates() {
        this.from = this.from.toISOString().split('T')[0]
    }
```

How can I store dates in mysql database with strict mod enabled using TypeORM?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL datetime literals don't support the 'Z' suffix used in ISO-8601 format to indicate UTC time zone.

Example:

```
mysql> select date('2022-08-22T00:00:00.000Z') as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2022-08-22 |
+------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                        |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2022-08-22T00:00:00.000Z' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select date('2022-08-22T00:00:00.000') as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2022-08-22 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that there is no warning issued when I take off the 'Z'.

---

According to this issue, your usage is correct: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1394

There is a comment:

> You need to setup reflect-metadata properly and tsconfig properly. There are docs how to setup them.

I am not a TypeORM user, so I have no idea about that. You can search for the documentation mentioned in that comment as well as I can.

Comment: Thank you, that's clear. but how do I do this with TypeORM? I have a column of type Date and I store it in the database and the conversion to ISO format is done by the framework itself. I just assign date `from = new Date()`